# WiFi options only appear after hard reset

Tags: internet

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my HP 15 laptop with an i5-7200U 2.50GHz and 16GB RAM. I scrubbed my HDD and started from scratch with what I believe is a good quality ISO.

Everything seemed like it installed OK but it did not give me any options upfront for WiFi.

I checked my adapters and it was recognizing them but I couldn't figure out how to get WiFi set up with them so I eventually plugged in Ethernet and it worked.

After a few min or so the WiFi options appeared. I didn't do anything in the terminal or to the system on my end. I thought this was weird.

When I rebooted the first time I lost the internet options again.  The only way I can get it back is to physically hold the power button and power it off, wait 10-15 sec, and power it back on. Doing that gives me WiFi again.

It also seems like it is way slower than it should be. Performance was better on Windows.

How can I get the WiFi options to appear without having to force reset?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This is a question & answer site. It has certain rules. Please focus on one issue at a time. You asked two questions: wireless problem and performance. Please [edit] your question and leave only one issue. Also please remove the narrative, it doesn't help to get a solution. After that we can ask you about harware details and suggest a solution. You can also ask another question about the other problem now or later.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. This will show your wireless device. You wrote that you've "checked" them, but we can't guess what they are.